# Random routes with trailing slash in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, trailing-slash

I'm having some "issues" with a project in Nuxt.js. I have created three pages: `register.vue`, `login.vue` and `index.vue`.

I was trying to do some functions with middleware in order to redirect between views in case that one user was logged in or not.

The thing is that i realized that in the browser, the 'register' page router shows like: `localhost:xx/register/` and the login and index pages routes shows like: `localhost:xx/login` and `localhost:xx/`

The problem is why it appears a trailing slash in the register view and no in the others.

I have tried the:

```
trailingSlash: false
```

in the `nuxt.config.js`, and although it quits the trailing slash from the url, if I use the command:

```
$nuxt.$route.path
```

for obtaining the path, it still remains with the '/' in the case of the register view.

Any idea about this? Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of code, this is properly displaying the route path

```html
<script>
export default {
  fetch({ route }) {
    console.log(route.path)
  },
}
</script>
```

[image]

PS: I do also have `trailingSlash: false`.